# Search in database table returns different result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query:

```
select Title
from dbo.posts
where CAST(CHARINDEX(N'mão', [Title]) AS int) > 0
```

This returns a record as expected. If I replace "mão" by "mao" I get no record.

My database collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS. I created the database using:

```
create database MyDb
on primary ( 
  size = 40MB,
  maxsize = 2GB,
  filegrowth = 20MB 
)
log on ( 
  size = 4MB,
  maxsize = 200MB,
  filegrowth = 2MB 
)
collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
go
```

What might be wrong?

Thank you,
Miguel

Comment: Presumably what's wrong is that you have one title with "mão" and no titles with "mao" in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS` is AS = Accent Sensitive. If you need to get also the rows congaing the `mao` then you need an Accent Insensitive collation.

Example of AS / AI collations (note: UNION remove duplicates):

```
PRINT 'Test #1' -- AS : mão and mao are different words
SELECT N'mão' collate Latin1_General_CI_AS AS Col1 
UNION
SELECT N'mao' collate Latin1_General_CI_AS AS Col1 

PRINT 'Test #2' -- AI: mão and mao are similar words
SELECT N'mão' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI AS Col2 
UNION
SELECT N'mao' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI AS Col2
```

Results:

```
Test #1
Col1
----
mão
mao
(2 row(s) affected)

Test #2
Col2
----
mão
(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

It all has to do with the collation 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'.  Ignore case, but check accent.

Therefore the word **mão** and **mao** are different.

Here is a reference from MSDN with a couple examples.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886.aspx

If you force the collation to be Accent Insensitive, you should get your record back.

TSQL Code Snippet:

```
-- Ignoring accents will return the data record
SELECT Title
FROM dbo.posts
WHERE 
    Title COLLATE Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI 
    LIKE '%mao%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI;
```